# Wann wird der Ausdruck »am Herd stehen« verwendet?

Tags: word-usage, idiom

Ich habe eigentlich diesen Ausdruck auf der Webseite *Wiktionary* gefunden, aber leider wurde er nicht in einem Satz verwendet. Ich werde einen damit bilden, aber ich weiß nicht, ob er sinnvoll sein wird:

> Ich stehe Currywurst am Herd.

Wann und in welchem Zusammenhang wird dieser Ausdruck benutzt?

Comment: Was soll man dazu sagen? Jemand steht am Herd (und nicht am Tisch, am Bücherregal, an der Tür); meistens ist das kein Zufall. Transitiv ist es natürlich nicht.

Comment: Der Ausdruck bedeutet "kochen" oder " etwas zubereiten".

Comment: Sprüche wie "Frauen gehören an den Herd" werden häufig von Machos verwendet um Arbeit+Bildung von Frauen zu kritisieren. Die Bedeutung ist, dass Frauen sich um den Haushalt (und ihren Mann/ihre Kinder) kümmern sollen, z. B. durch das Kochen/Zubereiten von Mahlzeiten (am Herd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In der trivialen Bedeutung mag '*Ich stehe am Herd'* einen Aufenthaltsort bezeichnen, wie '*an der Spüle*' oder '*am Tresen*'.

*'Am Herd stehen'* heißt der Koch zu sein und könnte benutzt werden wie 'Tim Mälzer steht am Herd'. Übertragen kann es aber auch heißen, dass man der Macher ist, die Kontrolle über die Prozesse hat, aber eben nicht fern der Dinge im Büro oder auf dem Papier, bzw. dass man beschäftigt ist und nicht Smalltalk mit den Gästen treibt: '*Sieglinde wird Euch Gesellschaft leisten - ich stehe am Herd*'.

Da Currywurst gegrillt wird würde man nicht sagen '*Ich stehe am Currywurstherd*' aber vielleicht '*Ich stehe am Currywurstgrill*' und da Currywurst, außer vielleicht in Märchen und Comics, keine Beine hat und nicht stehen kann, sondern umfällt, steht eine Currywurst eher selten am Herd. Ein Adjektiv ist es auch nicht, so dass allenfalls '*Ich stehe currywurstfettig* am Herd' denkbar ist.

Answer (score 1):

Der in der Frage stehende Satz ist falsch.

Der folgende Satz ist hingegen korrekt:

> Ich stehe am Herd.

Dieser Satz gibt Auskunft über meinen Aufenthaltsort (Wo stehe ich? - am Herd) und darüber was ich dort mache (Was mache ich am Herd? - stehen). Natürlich gibt der Satz auch bekannt wer am Herd steht (nämlich ich).

Man kann diesen Satz natürlich auch um eine Currywurst erweitern, aber nicht so, wie das in Frageposting gemacht wurde. Da fehlen nämlich eine Präposition und ein Artikel:

> Ich stehe **mit einer** Currywurst am Herd.

Der Satz sagt vordergründig aus, dass ich gemeinsam mit einer Currywurst am Herd stehe. Da Currywürste aber für gewöhnlich nicht selbstständig stehen, wird dieser Satz für gewöhnlich so interpretiert, dass das *Ich* des Satzes die Wurst in der Hand hält, sie gerade isst, oder sie gerade zubereitet. Näheres muss dem Kontext oder der eigenen Fantasie entnommen werden.

Generell kann man sagen, dass der Ausdruck

> am Herd stehen

immer dann verwendet wird, wenn sich jemand in aufrechter Haltung (also stehend) in unmittelbarer Nähe (»am«) eines Gerätes befindet, das zur thermischen Zubereitung von Speisen dient (letzteres nennt man einen »Herd«).

Häufig ist gemeint, dass die Person, die am Herd steht, diesen auch gerade benutzt um darauf Speisen zu erhitzen. Das muss aber nicht zwangsweise der Fall sein. Man kann auch an einem kalten Herd stehen und sich mit einer andern Person unterhalten, oder dort eine Currywurst essen.

Answer (score 1):

Natürlich lässt sich *stehen* um eine optionale Ortsangabe ergänzen:

> *Ich stehe hier.*
>   *Ich stehe vor der Tür.*
>   *Ich stehe an der Tür.*
>   *Ich stehe auf dem Balkon.*
>   *Ich stehe an einem Herd.*
>   *Ich stehe am Herd.*

In vielen Fällen impliziert das eine weitere dort ausgeführte Handlung, z.B. mit ansteigender Stärke der Assoziation: das Rauchen auf dem Balkon, das Klingeln oder Klopfen und Warten an der Tür, oder das Kochen am Herd.

Gerade der letzte Fall *am Herd stehen*, um den es in der Frage geht, wird auch im übertragenen Sinne für eine Profession verwendet. Das könnte also Köche bezeichnen, aber häufiger wird es für Hausmänner und (vor allem) Hausfrauen verwendet.

In manchen Dialekten kann *am* statt nur für *an einem* oder *an dem* auch für *auf einem* oder *auf dem* stehen.

> „Mein kleiner grüner Kaktus steht draußen **am** Balkon.“ — Comedian Harmonists

Wenn nun also die Currywurst ins Spiel kommt, kann ich sie entweder gerade auf dem Herd kochen bzw. braten, sie neben dem Herd auf der Anrichte bereitgelegt haben oder sie schon in der Hand halten:

> *Die Currywurst steht **am** Herd.* ← ‚auf dem‘ oder ‚neben dem‘
>   *Ich stehe **mit (der) Currywurst** am Herd.* – noch in der Pfanne oder schon in der Hand
>   *Ich stehe am Herd mit der Currywurst.*

Das letzte dieser Beispiele kann auch verstanden werden als nähere Bestimmung eines Herdes von mehreren, z.B. in einer Großküche. 
Ohne Präposition kann die Currywurst hier nicht stehen, da sie das Stehen nicht näher (adverbial) bestimmt, wie es hier der Fall wäre:

> *Ich stehe **kochend** am Herd.*
>   *Ich stehe **immer** am Herd.*
>   **Ich stehe **Currywurst** am Herd.*

Falls trotzdem *ich* das Subjekt und *Currywurst* ein Objekt sein soll, gäbe es selbstverständlich auch Möglichkeiten:

> *Ich **habe** eine Currywurst auf dem Herd **stehen**.* – impliziert eine Pfanne
>   *Ich **stelle** eine Currywurst auf **den** Herd.* – dito

Answer (score 1):

*Am Herd stehen* ist ein oft verwendeter, idiomatischer Ausdruck für *kochen* (und vergleichbare Küchenarbeiten, die der Essenszubereitung dienen, wie *backen*). Allerdings ist Vorsicht geboten.

*Kochen* kann transitiv (*etwas kochen*) oder intransitiv verwendet werden. In der transitiven Verwendung wird das Akkusativobjekt durch Einwirkung von Hitze in eine essbare oder genießbarere Form überführt. Beispiel:

> Ich koche *Wasser.* (Ich stelle einen Topf auf den Herd, tue Wasser hinein und erhitze das bis zum sieden.)
>
> Ich koche *Nudeln.* (In das siedende, salzige Wasser werfe ich harte Nudeln und warte, bis sie gar sind.)
>
> Ich koche mir mal *etwas.* (Ich gehe in die Küche und suche etwas essbares, das ich mir auf dem Herd zubereiten kann.)

Diese transitive Verwendung kann **nicht** durch *am Herd stehen* ersetzt werden, es wäre also **falsch** zu sagen:

> <strike>Ich stehe am Herd Nudeln.</strike>

---

Eine intransitive Verwendung von *kochen* beschreibt allgemein in die Küche gehen und dort etwas essbares zubereiten, ohne zu spezifizieren, was genau.

> Ich koche heute.
>
> Ruf mich später wieder an, ich koche gerade.
>
> Der Eine kocht, der Andere spült ab.

**Diese und nur diese Verwendung von *kochen*** kann stets durch *am Herd stehen* ersetzt werden:

> Ich stehe heute am Herd.
>
> Ruf mich später wieder an, ich stehe gerade am Herd.
>
> Der Eine steht am Herd, der Andere an der Spüle.

---

Zuletzt gibt es noch eine dritte Verwendung von *kochen*, nämlich *sieden* – außerhalb von chemischen Laboren wird sie hauptsätzlich für Wasser benutzt.

> Wasser *kocht* bei hundert Grad.

Es wäre sehr lustig sich vorzustellen, wie Wasser bei Erreichen von 100 °C aus dem Topf herausspringt und sich an den Herd stellt — und deswegen kann man den Ausdruck hierfür ebenfalls **nicht** verwenden.